# libid3tag is required to compile mpg321 - but libid3tag is installed

Tags: c++, linux, compiler-errors, raspberry-pi

So I am trying to compile mpg321 on my Raspberry Pi running Pidora.
However when running ./configure I get the error:

```
configure: error: "libid3tag is required to compile mpg321 - version 0.14.1 or better."
```

However I have the package

```
libid3tag-0.15.1b-13.fc18.armv6hl
```

installed.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It needs the libid3tag-devel package.

Edit: From the config.log it also needs libz (/bin/ld: cannot find -lz - while checking for id3tag) - so you also need to install zlib (and zlib-dev maybe) packages to get past this.

Comment: Both packages are now installed but I still get the same error

Comment: Probably something to do with config.cache - can you delete that file and retry? If not post the last few entries from config.log. (Just to be sure the package is called libid3tag-devel on Fedora - that's the one you installed right?)

Comment: Where would I find the config.cache? and yes I installed libid3tag-devel

Comment: It doesn't always exist - but if it does, it should be in the root of the source folder - where you ran the configure script from. Failing that there should at least be config.log in the same location - posting the error from the last few lines of that file will tell us why it is not finding the libid3tag.

Comment: here is teh config.log do not seem to have a config.cache http://pastebin.com/Q3YBsdj8